# Centroid of area enclosed by $x^n$ and $x^{1/n}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics, centroid

I am interested in finding the centroid of the surface enclosed by the lines $y=x^n$ and $y=x^{1/n}$ where $n \in \mathbb N, n >1$. The exercise, gives the following sketch.

[image]

I know that in order to find the centroid, we need to calculate its $x$ and $y$ coordinates, namingly :

$$x_c = \frac{\iint_A x \mathrm{d}A}{A} , \; y_c = \frac{\iint_A y \mathrm{d}A}{A}$$

Now, since $n>1$ I think that the only two points that the two lines meet are at $0$ and $1$. Thus, the area should be :

$$A = \int_0^1 ( x^{1/n} - x^n)\mathrm{d}x = \left[ \frac{x^{1/n + 1}}{1/n + 1}- \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} $$

I am having a bit of a struggle now, though, calculating the numerator quantities. Please, correct me if I am wrong in my approach for them as follows :

$$\iint_A x\mathrm{d}A = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{y^{1/n}} x \mathrm{d}x \right) \mathrm{d}y, \; \iint_A y\mathrm{d}A = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{x^{1/n}}y\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Botond Yeah, typo. Thanks for checking, I hate this type of stuff :D.

Comment: Sorry I think the limits are not good, but I need to think a bit.

Comment: @Botond The limits are what I worry about. Sure, take your time !

Comment: In the first case, let's fix an $y$ for the inner integral. Then $x$ need to be between $x^{1/n}=y$ and $x^n=y$, so the inner limits are $y^n$ and $y^{1/n}$.

Comment: @Botond Yeah you're correct, the value $0$ is achieved when $y = 0$ which is taken into account in the outer integral.

Comment: And the limits of the other integrall will be the same, just $x$ and $y$ will be swapped (due to symmetry)

Comment: By symmetry, the centroid will be on the line $x=y.$

Comment: Rather than $\int_0^{y^{1/n}}$ it should be $\int_{y^n}^{y^{1/n}}$

Comment: Can simplify $$A=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$$

Comment: More generally, if $0<b<a$ then the centroid the region between $x^a$ and $x^b$ is $$\left(\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+2)(b+2)},\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(1+2a)(1+2b)}\right)$$ When $a=n$ and $b=1/n$ then this is $$\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)(1+2n)},\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)(1+2n)}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\iint_A x\mathrm{d}A = \int_0^1 \left( \int_{y^n}^{y^{1/n}} x \mathrm{d}x \right) \mathrm{d}y$$

$$= \int_0^1 \left[\frac {x^2}2 \right]_{y^n}^{y^{1/n}}  \mathrm{d}y$$

$$= \frac 12 \int_0^1 \left[y^{\frac 2n}-y^{2n} \right] \mathrm{d}y$$

$$= \frac 12  \left[\frac{y^{\frac 2n+1}}{\frac 2n+1}-\frac{y^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \right]_0^1 $$

$$= \frac 12  \left[\frac{y^{\frac {2+n}{n}}}{\frac {2+n}{n}}-\frac{y^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \right]_0^1 $$

$$= \frac 12  \left[\frac{1}{\frac {2+n}{n}}-\frac{1}{2n+1} \right] $$

$$= \frac{n}{2(2+n)}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$$

$$= \frac{n(2n+1)-(2+n)}{2(2+n)(2n+1)}$$

$$= \frac{2n^2-2}{2(2+n)(2n+1)}$$

$$= \frac{n^2-1}{(2+n)(2n+1)}$$